# Is there a way to plot a Line2D in points coordinates in Matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, transform

It is very straight forward to plot a line between two points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` in `Matplotlib` using `Line2D`:

```
Line2D(xdata=(x1, x2), ydata=(y1, y2))
```

But in my particular case I have to draw Line2D instances using Points coordinates on top of the regular plots that are all using Data coordinates. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @tom mentioned, the key is the `transform` kwarg. If you want an artist's data to be interpreted as being in "pixel" coordinates, specify `transform=IdentityTransform()`.

### Using Transforms

Transforms are a key concept in matplotlib. A transform takes coordinates that the artist's data is in and converts them to display coordinates -- in other words, pixels on the screen.

If you haven't already seen it, give the [matplotlib transforms tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) a quick read.  I'm going to assume a passing familiarity with the first few paragraphs of that tutorial, so if you're

For example, if we want to draw a line across the entire figure, we'd use something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# The "clip_on" here specifies that we _don't_ want to clip the line
# to the extent of the axes
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], lw=3, color='salmon', clip_on=False, 
        transform=fig.transFigure)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**This line will *always* extend from the lower-left corner of the figure to the upper right corner, no matter how we interactively resize/zoom/pan the plot.**

---

### Drawing in pixels

The most common transforms you'll use are `ax.transData`, `ax.transAxes`, and `fig.transFigure`.  However, to draw in points/pixels, you actually want no transform at all.  In that case, you'll make a new transform instance that does nothing: the `IdentityTransform`.  This specifies that the data for the artist is in "raw" pixels.

---

Any time you'd like to plot in "raw" pixels, specify `transform=IdentityTransform()` to the artist.

---

If you'd like to work in points, recall that there are 72 points to an inch, and that for matplotlib, `fig.dpi` controls the number of pixels in an "inch" (it's actually independent of the physical display).  Therefore, we can convert points to pixels with a simple formula.

As an example, let's place a marker 30 points from the bottom-left edge of the figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import IdentityTransform

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

points = 30
pixels = fig.dpi * points / 72.0

ax.plot([pixels], [pixels], marker='o', color='lightblue', ms=20,
        transform=IdentityTransform(), clip_on=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

### Composing Transforms

One of the more useful things about matplotlib's transforms is that they can be added to create a new transform.  This makes it easy to create shifts.

For example, let's plot a line, then add another line shifted by 15 pixels in the x-direction:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10), color='lightblue', lw=4)

ax.plot(range(10), color='gray', lw=4,
        transform=ax.transData + Affine2D().translate(15, 0))

plt.show()
```

[image]

A key thing to keep in mind is that the order of the additions matters.  If we did `Affine2D().translate(15, 0) + ax.transData` instead, we'd shift things by 15 *data* units instead of 15 pixels.  The added transforms are "chained" (composed would be a more accurate term) in order.

[image]

---

This also makes it easy to define things like "20 pixels from the right hand side of the figure".  For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([1, 1], [0, 1], lw=3, clip_on=False, color='salmon',
        transform=fig.transFigure + Affine2D().translate(-20, 0))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`transform`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_transform) keyword to change between data coordinate (the default) and axes coordinates. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines

plt.plot(range(10),range(10),'ro-')

myline = lines.Line2D((0,0.5,1),(0.5,0.5,0),color='b') # data coords

plt.gca().add_artist(myline)

mynewline = lines.Line2D((0,0.5,1),(0.5,0.5,0),color='g',transform=plt.gca().transAxes) # Axes coordinates

plt.gca().add_artist(mynewline)

plt.show()
```

[image]